# How to add slider/range in store configuration?

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml, slider

[image]

any reference for adding this type of slider in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the phtml file that outputs the html.

For example,
in vendor/magento/module-tax/view/adminhtml/templates/items/price/row.phtml, you would extend this file by adding it to your module: app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/view/adminhtml/templates/items/price/row.phtml.

You would also need to extend the layout xml file that maps the templates file path, and replace the template attribute value with your modules template path,

example:

template="YourCompany_YourModule::items/price/row.phtml"

In a nutshell, you can extend admin phtml files the same way you would extend frontend files.